# Admob banner for IOS, Iphone and Ipad Landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, admob, landscape, banner

I need help with banner on IOS. I want banner to be on the bottom and to be smart banner full size on landscape for iPad ana iPhone. I have placed many codes from google or this forum but no one is helping me. If someone know something I will try. Regards

Comment: You tried this ? - https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start